# Showing Parent - Child model using Angular with net 6

Tags: angular

I am trying to show a Client and his list of contracts using Angular 13 and net 6.

I have this model in my WebApi:

```
namespace CompanyApi.Models
{
    public partial class Societaire
    {
        public Societaire()
        {
            Contrats = new HashSet<Contrats>();
        }

        public int IdClient { get; set; }
        public int Titre { get; set; }
        public int Sexe { get; set; }
        public string Nom { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Prenom { get; set; } = null!;

        public virtual ICollection<Contrats> Contrats { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Which represents a Customer and his contracts.
My controller for recovering the Customer detail by idClient :

```
  @Input() societaire:any;
  idClient: number = 0;
  titre: number = 0;
  sexe: number = 0;
  nom: string = "";
  prenom: string = ""; 
  contrats = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.societaireList$ = this.service.getSocietaireList();
    this.idClient = this.societaire.idClient;
    this.titre = this.societaire.titre;
    this.sexe = this.societaire.sexe;
    this.nom = this.societaire.nom;
    this.prenom = this.societaire.prenom;
    this.contrats = this.societaire.contrats
  }
```

When the view shows the data in the next form:

```
<form>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="id" class="form-label">Id</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="idClient" name="id">
      </div>
      
      
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="titre" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="sexe" class="form-label">sexe</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="sexe" name="sexe">
        
    </div>       
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="nom" class="form-label">nom</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="nom" name="nom">
        
    </div>   

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="prenom" class="form-label">prenom</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="prenom" name="prenom">
        
    </div>       

  
    <button (click)="updateSocietaire()" *ngIf="societaire.idClient!=0" class="btn btn-primary">
    Update
    </button>    

    <div class="mb-3">

        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <th>idClient</th>
              <th>idContrat</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                  <tr *ngFor="let item of societaire.contrats"> 
                    <td>{{item.idClient}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.idContrat}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>       
        
</form>
```

I can see the information about the header of the Customer entity but the form is not able to show the list of contracts.

Thank you in advance for your advice to solve this problem.

Comment: I imagine your service.getSocietaireList() return an observable (so is an async function), so you need subscribe to these and in subscribe function equal the variables. Really I don't know the reason you see the information about the header, seeing your code the data of your header should be empty.

Comment: With the "header" I mean the part before the Update button, the information before the Update button is visible, but the information that is supposed to be shown by the *ngFor (the list of the contracts) is missing.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Sorry my comment, I don't read your question with a great attention

You pass as input the `societaire`, so the apropiate place to equals your variables is in a "getter" of the input

```
societaire:value;
@Input('societaire') set _societaire(value:any){
    this.societaire=value;
    this.idClient = this.societaire.idClient;
    this.titre = this.societaire.titre;
    this.sexe = this.societaire.sexe;
    this.nom = this.societaire.nom;
    this.prenom = this.societaire.prenom;
    this.contrats = this.societaire.contrats;
    //put here to check if you has values
    console.log(this.contrats,this.idClient );
}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.societaireList$ = this.service.getSocietaireList();
  }
```

check if you received the contrats and the idClient in your getter using the console.log

check also if you has errors in console

Comment: Hi Eliseo, many thanks for your answer, in fact, you are right, when I write console.log in the to see the values of this.contrats the element is empty (length: 0). This means that the assignment this.contrats = this.societaire.contrats; is not working. However the service is returning the Client and the list of contracts. Any advice to detect where is the problem ?

Comment: I imagine your parent is like `<app-child [societaire]="societaire"></app-child>`. Is the "parent" who in his variable has no value in "contrats". Check in parent when you give value to the variable -I imagine that can be a "type error" (use contrast instead of contrats or some similar)-

Comment: Yes, I have in the parent : <app-add-edit-societaire [societaire]="societaire" *ngIf="activateApp"></app-add-edit-societaire> to call the child.